# Moongose query for finding unique document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

```json
json: {
  data:{
    base:"Id",
  },
  res:{
    message:"sddg"
  }
}
```

I want to find if a particular record already exist on the basis of base unique attribute using Mongoose in MongoDB database, but unable to do so.
My approach is:

```js
model.findOne({data:{base:"Id"});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do it like this:

```js
model.findOne("data.base": "Id")
```